# Jquery version 1.12.4 $(window).on is not a function

Tags: jquery

I searched whole internet and all i found is:

> Method on was introduced in jQuery version 1.7

but i checked my version with code below

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {  
    // jQuery is loaded => print the version
    alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);
}
```

It says the loaded one is version 1.12.4. i can't use `$(window).on('load',function(){})` and `$('body')` is null but `document.getElementsByTagName('body')` has stuffs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're using jQuery in "[no conflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)" mode, where `$` is not `jQuery`. It also sounds like `$` may be being used for another library like MooTools or PrototypeJS. (That bit about `$('body')` returning `null` sounds **very** much like MooTools or PrototypeJS, because with those libs, `$` is a shortcut for `getElementById` [effectively, with bugfixes around obsolete IE], and you probably don't have an element with `id="body"`.)

Use `jQuery` instead:

```
jQuery(window).on("load", function() { /*...*/ });
```

...or create an IIFE and make a local `$` that equals `jQuery`:

```
(function($) {
    // Here, $ === jQuery
    $(window).on("load", function() { /*...*/ });
})(jQuery);
```

---

Side note: The `load` event on `window` happens **very** late in the page loading process, waiting until all images and other resources are fully loaded. Depending on what you're doing in that `load` callback, you may want to use something else instead.

Personally, my preference is to put my scripts at the very end of the `body` element, just before the closing `</body>` tag, and use an IIFE like the above (at that point, all of the HTML has been parsed and you can act on the resulting elemenst). But a lot of people like jQuery's "ready" mechanism, which happens very slightly after that, and which when called correctly will also pass you an instance of `jQuery`:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // Here, $ === jQuery
});
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder how to find out what is the `$` ? cause its print exact same thing when i type it on `chrome's console`

Comment: @no0ob - Review the scripts you're loading. Beware that in some browser consoles, `$` (and sometimes `$$`) are defined even if your script doesn't define them (Chrome's devtools do that, for instance).

Comment: `$` is not for Id's only `$('#stuff')` is an Id actually

Comment: @no0ob - Gah, you're right (for Chrome's devtools), it's a wrapper for `querySelector`, not `getElementById`. (In MooTools and PrototypeJS, it's a wrapper for `getElementById`.)

Answer (score 0):

That syntax is deprecated.

You can use `$(window).scroll(function () { //your code goes here })`